# How to return to the game? after finishing the game

Tags: java

I am doing a TicTacToe Program, the only missing part is to have the user to choose whether to quit the game or to replay. I can't find a way to "return" to the gaming.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Expierment
{
        static char c1 [] = new char[10];
        static char c2 [] = new char[10];
        static char c3 [] = new char[10];
        static char p1;
        static char p2;
        static boolean gameOver = false;
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int p1Wins = 0;
            int p2Wins = 0;
            int r1 = 0;
            int r2 = 0;
            int r3 = 0;
            int r4 = 0;
            int r5 = 0;
            int r6 = 0;
            int r7 = 0;
            int r8 = 0;
            int r9 = 0;
            int pick1 = 0;
            int pick2 = 0;
            int pick3 = 0;
            int pick4 = 0;
            int pick5 = 0;
            int pick6 = 0;
            int pick7 = 0;
            int pick8 = 0;
            int pick9 = 0;
            char turn = 'X';
            int choice = menu();
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The game is called 'Tic-Tac-Toe', you should have known it. If you don't, search it.")  ;
                case 2:
                    gameOver = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\nSee you next time !!");
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.println("\nYou hit the wrong key......\n");
                    return;
            }//end of switch
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 1 initials ?");
            String n1 = GCS();
            p1 = n1.charAt(0);
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 2 initials ?");
            String n2 = GCS();
            p2 = n2.charAt(0);
            c1[2]='1';
            c2[2]='2';
            c3[2]='3';
            c1[1]='4';
            c2[1]='5';
            c3[1]='6';
            c1[0]='7';
            c2[0]='8';
            c3[0]='9';
        printBoard ();
        while(gameOver!=true)
        {
            System.out.println("Which spot ?");
            int pick = Integer. parseInt(GCS());
                switch (pick)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (r1<1)
                {
                    c1[2] = turn;
                    r1++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;                  
                case 2:
                    if (r2<1)
                {
                    c2[2] = turn;
                    r2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;                  
                case 3:
                    if (r3<1)
                {
                    c3[2] = turn;
                    r3++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (r4<1)
                {
                    c1[1] = turn;
                    r4++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if (r5<1)
                {
                    c2[1] = turn;
                    r5++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    if (r6<1)
                {
                    c3[1] = turn;
                    r6++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                case 7:
                    if (r7<1)
                {
                    c1[0] = turn;
                    r7++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if (r8<1)
                {
                    c2[0] = turn;
                    r8++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                case 9:
                    if (r9<1)
                {
                    c3[0] = turn;
                    r9++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("That column is full, pick another.\n");
                    continue;
                }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Seriously?! Pick a possible spot.\n");
                    continue;
                }//end of switch
            if (turn=='X') turn = 'O';
            else turn = 'X';
            printBoard();
            if (checkWinner())
            {
                while(gameOver==true)
                {
                    int Echoice = EGM();
                    switch(Echoice)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("The game is called 'Tic-Tac-Toe', you should have known it. If you don't, search it.")  ;
                        case 2:
                            gameOver = false;
                            menu();

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("\nSee you next time !!");
                            return;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("\nYou hit the wrong key......\n");
                            return;
                    }//end of switch
                }//end of while true
                return;
            }
            counter ++;
            if (counter==9)
            {
                System.out.println("\n\nYou tied.\n");
                return;
            }
        }//end of while not true
    }//end of main

    public static boolean checkWinner()
    {
            for (int k=0; k<2; k++)
        {
            if ((c1[k]!=' ')&&(c1[k]==c2[k])&&(c1[k]==c3[k]))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYo " + c1[k] + " is the winner!\n");
                gameOver=true;
                return true;
            }//checks column 1-3 horizontally
        }//end of horizontal check

        for (int m=0; m<2; m++)
        {
            if((c1[m]!=' ')&&(c1[m]==c1[m+1])&&(c1[m+1]==c1[m+2])&&(c1[m]==c1[m+2]))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYo " + c1[m] + " is the winner!\n");
                gameOver=true;
                return true;
            }//checks column 1 vertically
            if((c2[m]!=' ')&&(c2[m]==c2[m+1])&&(c2[m+1]==c2[m+2])&&(c2[m]==c2[m+2]))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYo " + c2[m] + " is the winner!\n");
                gameOver=true;
                return true;
            }//checks column 2 vertically
            if((c3[m]!=' ')&&(c3[m]==c3[m+1])&&(c3[m+1]==c3[m+2])&&(c3[m]==c1[m+2]))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYo " + c3[m] + " is the winner!\n");
                gameOver=true;
                return true;
            }//checks column 3 vertically
                if ((c1[m]!=' ')&&(c1[m]==c2[m+1])&&(c1[m]==c3[m+2]))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYo " + c1[m] + " is the winner!\n");
                gameOver=true;
                return true;
            }//checks upward diagonal
                if ((c3[m]!=' ')&&(c3[m]==c2[m+1])&&(c3[m]==c1[m+2]))
            {
                System.out.println("\nYo " + c1[m] + " is the winner!\n");
                gameOver=true;
                return true;
            }
        }//end of vertical check
                return false;
    }//end of checkWinner

    public static void printBoard()
    {
        System.out.println("_______");
        for (int j = 2; j > -1; j--)
        {
            System.out.println("|" + c1[j] + "|" + c2[j] + "|" + c3[j] + "|");
            System.out.println("-------");
        }
    }//end of printBoard

    public static int menu()
    {
        System.out.println("Tic-Tac-Toe ~ Main Menu\n\n1. Instructions\n2. Play a 1 player game"+"\n3. Exit\n");
        int selection = Integer.parseInt(GCS());
        return selection;
    }//end of menu

    public static int EGM()
    {
        System.out.println("Tic-Tac-Toe ~ End of Game Menu\n\n1. Instructions\n2. Play again"+"\n3. Exit\n");
        int Eselection = Integer.parseInt(GCS());
        return Eselection;
    }

    public static String GCS()
    {
        int noMoreInput=-1;
        char enterKeyHit='\n';
        int InputChar;
        StringBuffer InputBuffer = new StringBuffer(100);

        try
        {
            InputChar=System.in.read();
            while(InputChar != noMoreInput)
            {
                if((char)InputChar !=enterKeyHit)
                {
                    InputBuffer.append((char)InputChar);
                }
                else
                {
                    InputBuffer.setLength(InputBuffer.length()-1);
                    break;
                }
                InputChar=System.in.read();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException IOX)
        {
            System.err.println(IOX);
        }
        return InputBuffer.toString();
        }//end of GCS
}//end of public class
```

Comment: Independently of your question, you might want to consider rewriting this code to eliminate the need for the `pick1`, `pick2`, ..., `pick9` variables.  If you ever find yourself writing out a collection of variables that look like this, you can almost always rewrite it by using an array, as in `int[] pick = new int[9]`.  This allows you to access all of the values as `pick[0]`, ..., `pick[8]`, but more importantly it lets you generate the indices programmatically.  This can let you compress your `switch` statement down to only a few lines of code if you're willing to take the time.

Comment: A few hints, r1-r9, pick1-pick9, use arrays instead, same with your cs, change them to an array of strings, and init them like this c[0]="741";

Comment: also things like gameOver!=true are redundant, instead use !gameOver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should get some of that code out of the `main` function.

Specifically, I'd put the whole game loop in a separate function, maybe called `playGame()`, which contains the logic for playing the game, checking winner, etc., and either returns the winner or just prints the winner and returns void.

Then the main function could put a call to `playGame()` in a loop, and at the end of the loop, ask the user if s/he wants to play again.

In general, you want each function to do **one** logical task. You've done well with moving `checkWinner` out, now do the same with some of the other code.

If you need help on the "asking the user about playing again", leave a comment and I'll make an edit to address that.

Answer (score 1):

```
quick and dirty pseudo-code - not modular

do {    
   //everything in your main goes here
   .
   .
   .    
   playAgain = prompt the user
} while(playAgain);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even dirtier than the do-while method. Will eventually cause stack-overflow.

```
//your current main method
boolean playAgain = prompt the user
if(playAgain){
    main(args);
}
```

Comment: +1 for stinkiest easiest code. I feel like a wash after reading this one.

Comment: this will SO if you play enough.

Comment: @Amir Afghani isn't that what my second sentence says?

Comment: I missed that Titan, I was sucked into the recursive vortex ;)

Answer (score 1):

With the current program layout, there is no "clean" way to accomplish that. Here are some constructive criticism :

- **Your main method should only be a bootstrapper**

You should only initialize your program in your `main` method. Consequently, try to have **1** method doing only **1** thing. You're design now has the game menu and game main loop inside the same method.

Your game loop could look like this:

```
while still playing
   read input from user
   if game is active
      process game input
      update game
   else
      process menu input
      update menu
```

This way, you only need to swith the `game is active` state for the menu or the game. Etc.

- **Do not [reinvent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)**

Your `GCS` method is way too complicated, just replace it with :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner();     // put this somewhere at the class level (so it is reusable)
...
String input = scanner.nextLine();   // put this somewhere in a method reading an input
```

- **Variable abuse**

Instead of initializing many variables, perhaps (like other have suggested) you could use arrays, or more specifically a 2-dimensional array.

```
int grid[][] = new int[3][3];
// grid[0][0] points to the top-left cell, grid[2][2] points to the bottom right one
```

Or you could use a single int to store everything; represent your grid as a [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)

```
int grid = 0;   // empty grid
...
// set player move
grid |= (1 << (y*3)+x) << PLAYER_OFFSET;  // PLAYER_OFFSET: 0=player 1, 16=player 2
// reset (clear) player move
grid &= ~((1 << (y*3)+x) << PLAYER_OFFSET); // ...
// check if player move is set
boolean isSet = (grid >> ((1 << (y*3)+x) << PLAYER_OFFSET)) && 1;   // ...
```

Why are bit arrays cool? Because to check if a player wins, you don't need fancy `for..loop` and other complicated algorithms, just validate against a winning pattern... :

```
int pattern = 273; // test for diagonal from [0,0] to [2,2], or bits "100 010 001"
boolean isWinning = (grid && (pattern << PLAYER_OFFSET)) != 0;
```

That's it!

---

Also, using `0` to `9` may be good to identify the grid cell, however as input value is not *that* intuitive for a player. Many games (chess, checkers, LOA, etc.) and applications (Excel, Calc, etc.), for example, are using the [Algebraic chess notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_chess_notation) system. Converting the notation in `x` and `y` is very simple. For example :

```
boolean cellPlayed = false;
while (!cellPlayed) {
   String cellStr = scanner.readLine().toLower();   // ex: "b2" for the center cell
   try {
      int gridx = cellStr.charAt(0) - 'a';   // ex: for "b2" should return 1
      int gridy = cellStr.charAt(1) - '1';   // ex: for "b2" should return 1

      grid(gridx][gridy] = playerValue;      // 1 for "player 1" and 2 for "player 2"
      cellPlayed = true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error! Invalid input");
   }
}
```

Don't feel discouraged! We all start somewhere! :)

Answer (score 0):

Things would be a lot more clear with a more concise main method. The really quick and dirty way would be to copy everything in your main method into a new method and just call that method from the main and when the user chooses to start a new game.

Comment: but then how about when the second game end

Comment: essentially the goal is to have similar to what is called a game loop. You have a method like playGame() that initializes your values, prints the board, etc. Call this from main. Once the game is finished you ask the user what to do next. To keep it simple you can use a Scanner object reading from System.in Once they give you an answer if they say play again you loop back to playGame and start over. The second game is no different than the first, or the third, etc. As long as you call playGame() you are basically starting fresh.